# ITextSharper,position of string inside a paragraph

Tags: c#, itext

I need to add some space between values to make in centralized,i'm using blank space in strings ,but its not good,i need to put the strings in parameters in the same paragraph.

```
paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("Vlr Notas:" + VlrNotas + "                                                    Vlr Débitos:" + VlrDebito + "                                                  Data De Crédito:" + DtCredito, font2);
                paragraph.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                document.Add(paragraph);
```

I'm doing this,i need to put "VlrNotas" align left and in the center of the page the "VlrDébitos",is there a way to put in absoluto position?

Comment: That sounds like you're building a table, have you tried using a table for that purpose (and turning border-rendering off)?

Comment: I did that,thanks for the sugestion.